# Solve the given Bernoulli equation: $xy(1+xy^2)\frac {dy}{dx} = 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble with this equation. I know a method is to get $\frac {dy}{dx}$ by itself and then use the substitution $v=y^{1-n}$ but I am not sure how to put this equation into the proper format in the first place to use this. The format is:

$$
\frac {dy}{dx} + P(x)y = f(x)y^n
$$

Or if anyone knows another method I would gladly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

first thing you think is its y(x), how is this bernoulli?

try to consider x(y) so then $x'(y)=\frac{dx}{dy}$
and your equation becomes

$xy+x^2y^3=\frac{dx}{dy}$   its

$\frac{dx}{dy}-yx=y^3x^2$

$\frac{dx}{dy} +P(y)x=f(y)x^2$ substitute $v=x^{1-2}$  you will get some nice soultion x(y), if you need y(x) its inverse function of x(y), enjoy solving